# How to scrape javascript rendered websites with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape the following websites: https://sv.siman.com/
However, my experience doing web scraping has not prepared me for Javascript rendered websites. I initially attempted to use Beautifulsoup, but the source code does not contain the HTML code you get when inspecting the page. I then attempted to use html_requests, but I have not come too far since it appears to be working randomly. This is the initial code to get the links to the products in one category page:

```
import asyncio
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_pythonorg():
  r = await asession.get('https://sv.siman.com/moda/damas/blusas')
  print(r.html.absolute_links)

asyncio.run(get_pythonorg())
```

The error I usually get is asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop. However, other times the code works fine and I do not know why.

I have also given Selenium a shot, but so far I have only managed to open the website. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd 

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
driver.get("https://sv.siman.com/moda/damas/blusas")
button = driver.find_element_by_name("Clubes")
button.click

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Clubes"))
    )
    element.click
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Having explained that, I will know describe what I would like to achieve. I want to automatically access all product categories and go through the different products in order to extract the relevant information. I understand the logic of this process using Beautifulsoup and have built functioning scrpaers before, But I cant get this to work.

Comment: Since you are familiar with `BeautifulSoup` you can pass the `html` retrieved by `Selenium` to `BeautifulSoup` and process it further; `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)`. Sometimes it takes `Selenium` some time to dynamically load the page, so you could implement a `time.sleep(1)` or [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) between `driver.get` and `soup =`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @RJAdriaansen, it worked!